# Selenium Tests very slow in between individual tests

Tags: django, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Django 1.4, Selenium 2.53.1 and Chrome Webdriver 2.21 as my testing webdriver to test my Django app.

I initialize my class as such:

```
class SeleniumTest(LiveServerTestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    cls.display.start()
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    cls.driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    super(SeleniumTest, cls).setUpClass()

def setUp(self):

    settings.SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
    engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
    self.sessionStore = engine.SessionStore()
    self.sessionStore.save()
    username = 'hello'
    password = 'hello'
    self.cad_user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, email='hello@hello.com')
    self.cad_user.set_password(password)
    self.cad_user.save()

    try:
        self.get_url('login')
        if self.driver.title == 'Login':
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_password').send_keys(password)
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]').click()
```

An example one of my tests is below.  It tests a dropdown with multiple levels that appear after you move your mouse over them and checks that they go to correct link

```
def dropdown_check(self, header_ids, choice_id, title):
    choice = self.driver.find_element_by_id(choice_id)
    mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
    for header_id in header_ids:
        header_element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(header_id)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, header_id)))
        mouse.move_to_element(header_element)
        mouse.perform()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, choice_id)))
    choice.click()
    self.assertEquals(self.driver.title, title)

def test_my_status_navigation(self):
    self.dropdown_check(['menubar_my_status'], 'menubar_my_status', 'User Status')
```

I've tried these things:

1. I've timed the code for each test, they take less than a second.
2. I've also timed the setup and setupclass methods, and they take maximum 2 seconds.
3. I've set to set_page_load_timeout to 0 and it does not change overal execution time.
4. I've run the tests by adding one extra test each round and discovered that for each test there is an increase of around 40 seconds to the total test suite time.

Given this, the entire suite of 8 tests takes over 300+ seconds and I have no idea why. I'm sure the loading of Webdriver takes some time, but after each individual test ends, I can see the Webdriver just sit there and do nothing.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing the details. Can you show your test(s), how do initialize the webdriver, versions of the selenium and django, what browser and version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I've updated the question with what you mentioned! I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much. Could it be that the start of the virtual display takes most of the time? Could you measure what makes the most negative impact on the performance?

Comment: @alecxe I normally run without the virtual display (when I'm developing) and it takes the same amount of time.  I just checked, the whole setUpClass method only takes 2 seconds.

Comment: @alecxe That's also one of the problems I'm having, I'm not sure how to test/watch which lines are running with django tests to see what is impacting performance.

Comment: Well, you can go as straightforward as putting `time.time() - time_start` where `time_start` was set before. Put this around different blocks and see what takes what time. What about that `set_page_load_timeout()` - what if you decrease the timeout value?

Comment: @alecxe Yeah, I wrote a decorator and did that for all my methods and none of them are greater than 1 second each, save the setup/setUpClass methods.  I've set `set_page_load_timeout()` to 0 and nothing changed..

Comment: @alecxe I've successively larger numbers of test and have found out that it consistently increases in time by 40 seconds for each test added.  But the time for `setup()` is still only 2 seconds long, is there any other methods that happen before each method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest issue is that `LiveServerTestCase` is the slowest of all the test cases in the Django Project. It inherits from [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)

> TransactionTestCase inherits from SimpleTestCase to add some
>   database-specific features:
>
> Resetting the database to a known state at the beginning of each test
>   to ease testing and using the ORM.

and

> Django’s TestCase class is a more commonly used subclass of
>   TransactionTestCase that makes use of database transaction facilities
>   to speed up the process of resetting the database to a known state at
>   the beginning of each test.

Thus each of your tests results in the database being completely reset, which is really slow. One solution is to use the -k or --keep option.

```
./manage.py test -k myapp
```

This will cut off at least 100 seconds from your test execution time.

There is another solution that cannot be applied in all conditions because TestCase cannot be used for Selenium Tests. However you can write independent selenium tests that connect to the dev server to speed some tests up. In this case you use `unittest.TestCase` from from python instead of `django.test.testcases.TestCase`. That sounds totally confusing so let me give an example!

```
from unittest import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumTest(TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        # usual code to setup drivers etc

    def testSomething(self):
        self.driver.get('localhost:8000/somepage')

        # now you are connecting directly to the development server.  
        # this approach is not suitable for all requirements but 
        # very fast compared to using a LiveServerTestCase
```

Last but not least: Often you don't need LiveServerTestCase or selenium tests at all. It's much faster and easier to use the django [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/)

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed it down to something to do with Django and how it interacts with the database because I've run with `setup` and `setUpClass` as well as my test methods as:

```
def setUpClass(cls):
    pass
```

And the overall time does not change and changing the database to sqlite3 significantly decreases the total test time albiet some errors.