# Django selenium test hanging between tests

Tags: python, django, selenium, phantomjs

I can't figure out why my django selenium tests are so slow.

I have been working on test speed improvement in a Django application. I have written a number of Selenium tests but they have dramatically slowed down test turnaround time, with each selenium test taking approximately 25-40 seconds. I have been reading a lot about selenium test speed up and the vast majority of speed improvements are already implemented: PhantomJS headless browser, explicit waits, browser reuse between tests, find by css selector and atomic tests

I have added some timers to understand where the time is lost and I was surprised to find out that setUp takes on average 1.3s, teardown takes 0.001s and the entire test function from beginning to end ranges between 1s and 4s.

```
test_xyz(research.tests.abcde) ... /home/userxyz/.virtualenvs/xyz/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:734: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Time taken to setUp(): 1167 ms 
Page being opened: http://localhost:8081/abc/research/
Time taken to tearDown: 0 ms
ok
```

What really confuses me is the fact that after the test succeeds, with 'ok' being reported, the terminal holds on an empty row with the blinking bar for over 20s, before printing out the next test's name. An example of my timer is below:

```
def setUp(self):
    timer = time.time()*1000
    self.set_user()
    super(ResearchSeleniumTestCase, self).setUp()
    print('Time taken to setUp: %d ms ' % (time.time()*1000 - timer))
```

Here's my reusable browser function. A timer around it shows it takes 1.3s

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.selenium = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    super(ResearchSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Tests very slow in between individual tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988906/selenium-tests-very-slow-in-between-individual-tests)

Comment: I scanned through the entire stackoverflow, I can't believe I didn't see that. Yes it would appear I have an almost identical problem but unfortunately I do leverage on the SimpleTestCase class's client and LiveServerTestCase's url. I have replaced my dependency from LiveServerTestCase url but I feel like the SimpleTestCase.client will be a lot tougher to exclude. Am I going to have to accept the speed drop?